¿Como puedo guardar archivos modificados con el nombre de los archivos originales en un directorio distinto en r?
Tengo en un directorio muchos archivos de texto, a los cuales tengo que añadir información. Para ello, recorro un bucle que me lea todos los archivos y los modifique. Finalmente, quiero guardar los archivos modificados en un directorio distinto pero con el mismo nombre que el original. Con el siguiente código me aparece un error
lista_archivos <- list.files(getwd(), 
                          pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)

# Consulta SQL para seleccionar todas las filas de la tabla geneAttributes
query <- "SELECT geneName, geneDescription FROM geneAttributes"

# Ejecutar la consulta y almacenar los resultados en un dataframe
gene_attributes <- dbGetQuery(disgenet_data, query)

# Ver las primeras filas del dataframe
head(gene_attributes)

# Itera sobre cada archivo
for (archivo in lista_archivos) {
  datos_originales <- read.table(archivo, header = FALSE, quote = "\\\"")
  colnames(datos_originales) <- "geneName"

  # Fusionar los datos originales con los datos adicionales
  datos_fusionados <- merge(datos_originales, gene_attributes, by = "geneName", all.x = TRUE)

  # Escribir el archivo de texto modificado
  ruta_archivo_modificado <- file.path("C:/Users/ficheros")
  write.table(datos_fusionados, file = paste0("C:/Users/ficheros/", archivo, ".txt"), sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)

}


El error es el siguiente:
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  no se puede abrir la conexión
Además: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/ficheros/prueba.txt.txt': No such file or directory


Parece que el problema es con la inexistencia de un archivo llamado Alejandro_Virués.txt.txt al momento de importarlo, revisa que exista. Adicionalmente, mira que termina con .txt repetido.

@JilberUrbina sí, ya lo comprobado y modificado a Alejandro_Virués.txt, pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error. Cuando lo hago solo con ese fichero si que me funciona pero cuando intento leer todos en el bucle no

El mensaje te indica el error, la ruta C:/Users/ladymary/Nextcloud/MARIA/UNIVERSIDAD/MASTERS/NOCIONES BASICAS DE BIOINFORMATICA/TAREA3/ficheros_anotados/C:/Users/ladymary/Nextcloud/MARIA/UNIVERSIDAD/MASTERS/NOCIONES BASICAS DE BIOINFORMATICA/TAREA3/tarea2_ficheros_expresion_diferencial_v2/Alejandro_Virués.txt.txt está defectuosa (estas colocando dos rutas como si fuera una sola). Dentro del bucle, extrae el nombre del archivo para evitar que se duplique la ruta:
ruta_archivo_modificado <- file.path("C:/Users/ladymary/Nextcloud/MARIA/UNIVERSIDAD/MASTERS/NOCIONES BASICAS DE BIOINFORMATICA/TAREA3/ficheros_anotados")

for (archivo in lista_archivos) {
  datos_originales <- read.table(archivo, header = FALSE, quote = "\\\"")
  colnames(datos_originales) <- "geneName"
  
  # Fusionar los datos originales con los datos adicionales
  datos_fusionados <- merge(datos_originales, gene_attributes, by = "geneName", all.x = TRUE)
  
  # Extraer nombre
  nombre = gsub(".txt","", gsub(".*/", "", archivo))
  
  # Escribir el archivo de texto modificado
  write.table(datos_fusionados, file = paste0(ruta_archivo_modificado, nombre, ".txt"), sep = "\t", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
  
}


si, ya encontré el error y era que estaba duplicando, muchas gracias!
